how to interpolating into the bigger grid in python
i make big grid with this method ->
min_value = -0.04
max_value = 0.04
step_size = 0.0001
xvalues = np.arange(min_value, max_value + step_size, step_size)
yvalues = np.arange(min_value, max_value + step_size, step_size)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(xvalues, yvalues)

summed_temp = np.zeros_like(xx)

grid_coordinates = np.column_stack((xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()))

i have coordinates and value of the zero
next step : i have specefic location (x1,y1) target_location and 2d array as temp grid target_temp_grid = ishape_temp_grid[0][:, :, 0]
third step : i found clost neighbor to target location at my big grid that i made before now i have the  new target location nearest_center_point = grid_coordinates[nearest_index]
fourth step : i make the coordinates surrounded by nearest_center_point
with translate_grid function
fifth step : i get new coordinates with rotate the translated coordinates
sixth step : i want to interpolate my 2d temp grid ( ishape_temp_grid[0][:, :, 0] value that represent temp) into the bigger grid that i made before that currently filled with zero and change the zero the value that represent temperature
seventh step : plot the big grid with showing the point and temp
i stuck step sixth
i do not know how do since six and seven step.
what i tried
interpolated_temp = griddata(combined_rotated_coordinates, target_temp_grid.ravel(), (xx, yy), method='linear', fill_value=0)

error :   File "interpnd.pyx", line 193, in scipy.interpolate.interpnd._check_init_shape
ValueError: different number of values and points
OR
other ways that led to weird shape

You can use contourf() with a colorbar():
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata


def _interpolate(G, RC):
    min_value = -0.04
    max_value = 0.04
    step_size = 0.0001
    xvalues = np.arange(min_value, max_value + step_size, step_size)
    yvalues = np.arange(min_value, max_value + step_size, step_size)
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(xvalues, yvalues)
    summed_temp = np.zeros_like(xx)
    coords, temp = np.array(RC), G.ravel()
    summed_temp += griddata(coords, temp, (xx, yy), method='linear', fill_value=0)

    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
    plt.contourf(xx, yy, summed_temp, levels=100, cmap='hot')
    plt.colorbar(label='Temp')
    plt.scatter(coords[:, 0], coords[:, 1], c='blue', s=10, label='label')
    plt.xlabel('X')
    plt.ylabel('Y')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()


G = np.array([[15, 20, 25],
              [30, 35, 40],
              [45, 50, 55]])

RC = np.array([[-0.01, -0.01],
               [0.00, -0.01],
               [0.01, -0.01],
               [-0.01, 0.00],
               [0.00, 0.00],
               [0.01, 0.00],
               [-0.01, 0.01],
               [0.00, 0.01],
               [0.01, 0.01]])

_interpolate(G, RC)



thanks for answer but i receive . this error
ValueError: different number of values and points
for this part summed_temp += griddata(coords, temp, (xx, yy), method='linear', fill_value=0)

@flow Print the values before this line and see what the problem is.
